# ¿Se puede hacer un círculo con Map Control (WEB)?

Tags: genexus

Estoy con genexus 15 build 107258

Estimados, necesito saber si es posible realizar un círculo con el control Map en Web. Supongo que con : Latitud y longitud del centro y un radio debe ser posible, pero no encuentro la forma. Si pude realizar polígonos con n vértices....

Gracias saludos
Bruno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El [MapControl](https://marketplace.genexus.com/product.aspx?mapcontrol,en) no tiene esa funcionalidad, actualmente.

Es posible implementarla, según indica el api v3 de google (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple?hl=es-419). Para ello es necesario modificar el mapsproviders.js y definir en el Structure Data type Gxmap, el soporte de Circulos (centro y radio). Subiremos en breve esta funcionalidad, y te pasaremos desde esta consulta el link para obtenerlo.